# Pandasql Exception with OVER

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to use this line of code :

```
import pandasql as ps
df2["transaction per 30 minutes"] = ps.sqldf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM df OVER (PARTITION BY 'Card Number' ORDER BY 'Date' RANGE BETWEEN '30 minutes' PRECEDING AND '0 minutes' FOLLOWING)", locals())
df2["avg_transaction_30"] = ps.sqldf("SELECT AVG(Amount) FROM df OVER (PARTITION BY 'Card Number' ORDER BY Date RANGE BETWEEN '30 minutes' PRECEDING AND  '0 minutes' FOLLOWING)")
```

NB : delete 'locals()' or replace by 'globals()' don't solve the problem.

But I have this error :

```
PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "(": syntax error
[SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM df2 OVER (PARTITION BY 'Card Number' ORDER BY date RANGE BETWEEN '30 minutes' PRECEDING AND '0 minutes' FOLLOWING)]
(Background on this error at: )
```

http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8
(Same error with Average)

I load my dataframe like this :

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
```

My file is in the same directory as my Jupiter notebook file. I follow the link, but I still don't understand what's wrong.

And this line work :

```
ps.sqldf("SELECT * FROM df2")
```

So I guess is not a problem with my pandasql

My initial goal with this code is :

I want to know how many transactions a card number do for every 30 min interval, and also calculate in average how many transactions a client do per 30 minutes.

For example, I want to have something like (order by Card Number) :

| Card Number | interval | #transactions_30min | AVG_transactions_30min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 536518******2108 | 2015-05-11 00:00:01 - 00:30:00 | 2 | 5 |
| 536518******2108 | 2015-05-11 00:30:01 - 01:00:00 | 8 | 5 |
| 536518******2197 | 2015-05-11 00:00:01 - 00:30:00 | 6 | 8 |
| 536518******2197 | 2015-05-11 00:30:01 - 01:00:00 | 10 | 8 |

My database look like this :

| id | Card Number | Date | Amount | Fraud |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 536518******2108 | 2015-05-01 00:01:54 | 36.54 | No |
| 1 | 536518******2108 | 2015-05-01 00:03:46 | 36.54 | No |
| 2 | 453211******1239 | 2015-05-01 00:08:50 | 69.00 | No |
| 3 | 548827******1705 | 2015-05-01 00:27:00 | 193.43 | No |
| 4 | 531681******9778 | 2015-05-01 01:32:46 | 132.00 | No |
| 5 | 515117******4107 | 2015-05-01 02:10:26 | 161.00 | No |
| 6 | 432032******9111 | 2015-05-01 08:09:15 | 110.00 | No |
| 7 | 544540******7141 | 2015-05-01 08:30:16 | 159.50 | No |
| 8 | 554906******0358 | 2015-05-01 09:13:51 | 126.50 | Yes |
| 9 | 554906******0358 | 2015-05-01 09:15:28 | 126.50 | Yes |

So is it possible to use pandasql in my case ? If yes, how can I correct my request to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using pandas for all calculations, here is one approach:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

g = df.groupby(["Card Number", pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='30min')], sort=False)
df_out = g['Amount'].agg(['count', 'mean']).add_prefix('transactions30min_').reset_index()
```

Result:

```
print(df_out)

        Card Number                Date  transactions30min_count  transactions30min_mean
0  536518******2108 2015-05-01 00:00:00                        2                   36.54
1  453211******1239 2015-05-01 00:00:00                        1                   69.00
2  548827******1705 2015-05-01 00:00:00                        1                  193.43
3  531681******9778 2015-05-01 01:30:00                        1                  132.00
4  515117******4107 2015-05-01 02:00:00                        1                  161.00
5  432032******9111 2015-05-01 08:00:00                        1                  110.00
6  544540******7141 2015-05-01 08:30:00                        1                  159.50
7  554906******0358 2015-05-01 09:00:00                        2                  126.50
```